How to add Multiple field data with WordPress Rest API and Python
I want to add a featured image, and since I am using Yoast SEO, I also want to add a focus keyphrase, SEO title, and meta description using the Python REST API, but I don't know how to proceed further.
import requests
import json
import base64

url = "https://exampleurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" 
user = "Username" 
password = "application password" 
credentials = user + ':' + password 
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()) 
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')} 
post = {  'title'    : 'Test WP-API',   
          'content'  : 'This is my first post created using restAPI',  
          'status'   : 'draft', 
} 
responce = requests.post(url , headers=header, json=post)

print(responce.json())


Yoast will most likely be storing this info as post meta data, so you need to figure out the correct meta field names, and then provide them via the meta parameter.
